# STS-Secured Service EndorsingSupportingTokens support in java/metro

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish-4, java-metro-framework, netbeans-8

I have created a .NET WCF service described by a hand-written platform-agnostic WSDL file. The service is secured by an STS and this is expressed in the WSDL by an EndorsingSupportingTokens security policy element. I need to create a Java example client (preferably in NetBeans) for my service and it's a lot harder than I expected.

I've just tried working through the entire section 12.9.7 "STS Issued Token" of https://metro.java.net/2.3/guide/user-guide.pdf in hopes that I could get this working in a pure Java environment and then incrementally change it to work with my situation, but it doesn't work for me. I find that by fiddling with various settings I can get a variety of different error messages, but it never quite works.

So I can work out for sure that this is supported, is there any example of the following in NetBeans+Metro that I can just download and use? I've followed a number of step-by-step guides but something always goes wrong^.

- Client authenticates with STS using an X509 certificate
- STS sends client an encrypted SAML Assertion
- Client sends request to Service, with SAML Assertion in headers

^ I'm happy to get a tentative "No" answer, so I can begin the process of raising specific questions about all the things that have gone wrong.